# Contacts getting duplicated while adding raw contact based on phone number

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, rawcontacts

I am trying to add raw contacts for each of the phone numbers associated with all contacts in the Android contact list. When certain contacts have multiple phone numbers associated with it, android contact list shows the same contact multiple times. I want to aggregate those newly added raw contacts(based on the phone number) and shows under that contact.

What I did is, I queried to list all the contacts in the device by using below URI  `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`
Again queried all the phone numbers of each of the contacts returned by executing above query using the `URI`

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
```

Then created ClsContactList `class objects` for each of the contact, which contains contact's display name and an array of phone numbers associated with that contact. Finally, these objects added to a list and for each object in the list, called the attached function to create raw contact.

```
private static void addContact(Account account, ClsContactList ObjContact) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    int rawContactInsertIndex = operationList.size();
    for (String phoneNumber : ObjContact.PhoneNumbers) {
        operationList.clear();
        //Creating raw contact
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DEFAULT);
        //builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, ObjContact.getDisplay_name());
        operationList.add(builder.build());
        //INSERT NAME
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, ObjContact.getDisplay_name());
        operationList.add(builder.build());

        //INSERT MOBILE
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber); // Number of the person
        //builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
        operationList.add(builder.build());

        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.c99.SyncProviderDemo.profile");
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, "VOIP Call ("+phoneNumber+")");
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "Dialer App");
        builder.withYieldAllowed(true);
        operationList.add(builder.build());
        try {
            mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please have a look at the attached screen shot. Many thanks in advance.

Raw contacts in contact details activity

[image]

Contacts duplicated in Android contact list

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to query like this to get the filtered data by comparing the mime type.

`ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE` = `StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
     null, null, ContacsContract.Data.MIMETYPE +  "='" + 
ContactsContract.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my case, the problem is the duplication of contact while adding the raw contact. As in the attached screenshot, Contact named "Aaaaaa" duplicated since it has two phone number. Here I am trying to add raw contacts for each phone number associated with "Aaaaaa".